# simple formula to distribute inputs

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, summation

I need a simple formula to do some math for my inputs to generate max number of fixed values ..
Below i wrote a simple logic for the math 
lets say we have an object that will cost fixed numbers of 4 elements like this

```
a = 140 ;
b = 180 ;
c = 85 ;
d = 110 ;
```

and 4 inputs like this :

```
w = 14000 ;
x = 1000 ;
y = 800 ;
z = 1100 ;
```

if we compare the cost of the object to the inputs we will notice that for a vs w we may create 10 objects ..
but for b vs x it can't create more than 5 objects .
what i need to do is to distribute or separate the numbers in the 4 inputs between each others to get the max result of the first 4 values .
i don't know if there is kind of formula or algorithm to do this 
Thanks

Comment: $\lfloor \min(\frac{w}{a}, \frac{x}{b}, \frac{y}{c}, \frac{z}{d} ) \rfloor$.